# PayPal Sandbox Multi-Currency MYR

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, currency

I would like to ask if the following scenario is possible in Paypal Sandbox.

My Store currency is MYR.

Sample: MYR 187.45

My Business account has USD as primary currency. And in My Payment Receiving Preferences

Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold. and I selected:
 **Yes, accept and convert them to U.S. Dollars. Additional charges apply.**

When I click **Buy now**, I always got an error:

**SetExpressCheckout failed: Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2014%2d06%2d19T06%3a13%3a28Z [CORRELATIONID] => ece5b15d66df6 [ACK] => Failure [VERSION] => 72%2e0 [BUILD] => 11457922 [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10605 [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction%20refused%20because%20of%20an%20invalid%20argument%2e%20See%20additional%20error%20messages%20for%20details%2e [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Currency%20is%20not%20supported [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error )**

Having a hard time on this, Please help me . thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PayPal Currency Documentation](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/mc/mc_wa-outside&user_locale.x=en_US&change_locale.x=1&country.x=US&country=US&locale.x=en_US&pagetype=inside&beta=ce2&bn_r=o) Malaysian Ringgit (only for Malaysian members) MYR.

You can use the above link to assist you with your currency choices since it comes directly from the PayPal published currency list.

Comment: Hi @pp_MSI_Jenn I just wanna know if we can create a Malaysia account ( both Merchant and Personal accounts) in Malaysia it will be possible to used it in my store?

Comment: As long as you are in Malaysia you can create a personal and a business account. Just go to https://paypal.com and then create the account changing the country to Malaysia.